Load, relocate and execute function symbol from elf in bare-metal ARMv7-A system
Consider a minimal c source with a simple function symbol inside it like so(for now without any global or read-only variables):
main.c:
int test_mul(int arg) { return arg * 2; }

int main() {return 1;}

And build it as a position-independent & relocatable into an elf binary for target platform:

arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -O0 -g3 -pie -fPIC -fno-common -c
-fmessage-length=0 -MT"main.o" -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "main.c"
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wl,-r -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib
-mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=hard -Wl,-build-id=none -Wl,-T -Wl,lscript.ld -o "test.elf"  ./main.o   -Wl,--start-group,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group
-Wl,--start-group,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group

Here is the elf dump:
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 114 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND
     1: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1
     2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2
     3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3
     4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4
     5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5
     6: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6
     7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7
     8: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8
     9: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9
    10: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10
    11: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11
    12: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12
    13: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13
    14: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14
    15: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15
    16: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   16
    17: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   17
    18: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   18
    19: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   19
    20: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   20
    21: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   21
    22: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   22
    23: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   23
    24: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   24
    25: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   25
    26: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   26
    27: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   27
    28: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   29
    29: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   30
    30: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   32
    31: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   34
    32: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   36
    33: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   38
    34: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   39
    35: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS main.c
    36: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 $a
    37: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 wm4.0.c25aa8de64a6e0ef448
    38: 00002400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _supervisor_stack_end
    39: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __eh_framehdr_start
    40: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 ___CTORS_LIST___
    41: 00000400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _ABORT_STACK_SIZE
    42: 00002c00     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __supervisor_stack
    43: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 __exidx_end
    44: 00003400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _undef_stack_end
    45: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 __sbss_start
    46: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 __fixup_start
    47: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 __fixup_end
    48: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __mmu_tbl_start
    49: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   19 __sdata_start
    50: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 __DTOR_END__
    51: 00003000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __abort_stack
    52: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 __fini_array_end
    53: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 __rodata_end
    54: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 __data1_start
    55: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 __sbss2_end
    56: 00002400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __irq_stack
    57: 00000800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _SUPERVISOR_STACK_SIZE
    58: 0000200c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _heap_end
    59: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 __exidx_start
    60: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_end
    61: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 __rodata1_start
    62: 00000033     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   18 __ARM.attributes_end
    63: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 __tbss_start
    64: 00003400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __fiq_stack
    65: 0000000c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _heap_start
    66: 00000400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _IRQ_STACK_SIZE
    67: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   20 __sbss_end
    68: 00000400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _FIQ_STACK_SIZE
    69: 00003800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __undef_stack
    70: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 __CTOR_LIST__
    71: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 __sbss2_start
    72: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 __rodata_start
    73: 00100044     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _SDA_BASE_
    74: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 __data_end
    75: 0000000c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 HeapBase
    76: 00002000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _irq_stack_end
    77: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __eh_framehdr_end
    78: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   17 __fini_array_start
    79: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   23 __bss_start
    80: 00002000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _STACK_SIZE
    81: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 __tdata_start
    82: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   21 __tdata_end
    83: 00000028    28 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 main
    84: 00002000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _HEAP_SIZE
    85: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 __init_array_end
    86: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _stack_end
    87: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 ___DTORS_END___
    88: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   19 __sdata_end
    89: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 __sdata2_start
    90: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 __CTOR_END__
    91: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 ___DTORS_LIST___
    92: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   10 __DTOR_LIST__
    93: 00002c00     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _abort_stack_end
    94: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __preinit_array_end
    95: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 __sdata2_end
    96: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 ___CTORS_END___
    97: 00002000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __stack
    98: 0000200c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 HeapLimit
    99: 00003800     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _end
   100: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 __rodata1_end
   101: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 __data1_end
   102: 0000000c     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _heap
   103: 00000000    40 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    2 test_mul
   104: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   22 __tbss_end
   105: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 __init_array_start
   106: 00002000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _stack
   107: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 __data_start
   108: 00003000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _fiq_stack_end
   109: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 __preinit_array_start
   110: 00000400     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _UNDEF_STACK_SIZE
   111: 00100044     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS _SDA2_BASE_
   112: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __mmu_tbl_end
   113: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   18 __ARM.attributes_start

How can we get managed to load/relocate this elf into memory and try to call test_mul function according to target bare-metal environment?
Are there any elf loader solutions for this situation/environment to be used?
Or any practical guide for what should we consider to do this?

To begin with, build with optimizations enabled and no debug information. Then strip the executable of everything that's not needed (objcopy is also useful). I also recommend that you create a linker script to place sections in fixed locations, and then you don't need any relocation.

@Someprogrammerdude The whole idea is to dynamically load some relocatable elf binaries into memory with alignment and other details and then access symbols there, so fixed addresses are not useful in this context I suppose.

For a bare-metal environment without an OS or without a memory management unit (to handle things like virtual memory and address remapping), dynamic anything is usually a rather bad idea. Why do you need to load programs dynamically? What is the target system? What is your assignment and actual problem?

It's a carrier board equipped with dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 co-processor + FPGA with 1GB DDR3 memory. Up to this point, I think it's a matter of aligned memory allocation for different sections + handling different types of symbol relocation in run(load) time. BTW a bad idea is a generic term when it comes to tricky tasks ;) and also the business requirements are straightforward, we have a basic firmware that can load other tasks(user code) at startup or from different sources (network, etc.)
